# Site login with PHP MySQL Blowfish

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, blowfish, crypt

I am having a serious issue with trying to validate my password when logging into my site. I am using php to create a blowfish encrypted password with salt using the code below.

```
<?php
function cryptPass($p, $rounds = 9) {
$salt = "";
$saltChars = array_merge(range('A','Z'),range('a','z'),range('0','9'));
for($i = 0; $i < 22; $i++){
    $salt .= $saltChars[array_rand($saltChars)];    
}
return crypt($p, sprintf('$2y$%02d$', $rounds) . $salt);
}
?>
```

This works fine and the crypted password is put into my mysql database. the problem is on login it will not validate. this is the login script.

```
if(isset($_POST["u"])){
 // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
 include_once("php_includes/db_connect.php");
 // GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES AND SANITIZE
 $u = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $_POST['u']);
 include_once("php_includes/hasher.php");
 $p = (cryptPass($_POST['p']));
 // GET USER IP ADDRESS
$ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
 // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
 if($u == "" || $p == ""){
     echo "login_failed";
    exit();
 } else {
 // END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
     $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username='$u' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
     $db_id = $row[0];
     $db_username = $row[1];
    $db_pass_str = $row[2];
     if($p != $db_pass_str){
         echo "login_failed";
        exit();
     } else {
//goto the users account
```

should I not be running the cryptPass function on the incoming user data?

Also of note would be that the mysql database password column is set up as VARCHAR(255) so its got plenty of room. At this point the password crypts right, I am just not able to compare it to the one in database properly. This is my first real try with blowfish pieced together from tutorials all over, I wanted to get away from md5 as php.net advises. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for reading this.

Comment: Use a hash like sha-256 (not md5, as you mention), not encryption.

Comment: You should look at the examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php Store the output of `crypt()` alone (it will give you back the signature plus the hashed part), which will include the salt used.

Comment: ok so I DO need to store the salt as well? I've read a lot that the salt stored with the password will work because the crypt will know what how to read it since the crypt type (in this case blowfish) is part of the string?

Comment: Yes; what you get back from `crypt()` will include the salt either that you provided in the signature (see the man page for more details), or that was generated internally by `crypt()`. Then you would `crypt($user_input, $hashed_password) == $hashed_password`, since `crypt()` will know how to read what `crypt()` generated.

Comment: @PHaeLiX - Actually, I removed that comment since it was misleading. If you store `crypt()`s response entirely, you don't need to store a `salt` separately unless you weren't using `crypt` and were doing it all manually.

Comment: ok, thats what I thought, however how is my code of     if(crypt($p, $db_pass_str) != $db_pass_str){ any different from    crypt($user_input, $hashed_password) == $hashed_password?

Comment: That's not in the code you have posted above? You do `cryptPass($_POST['p'])` then compare that later. Why? You don't need to `cryptPass` again on what was submitted for login (this generates an entirely different salt), you simple do as you have in the comment above.

Comment: Ok I have changed    $p = cryptPass($_POST['p']); to simply    $p = $_POST['p]; and the if statement to    if(crypt($p, $db_pass_str) != $db_pass_str){  but its still not validating. to me it seems that there is no reason for this.

Comment: Then visually inspect the output like I have demonstrated below to make sure what you're expecting is happening, is happening. One thing I would change is to use an associative array instead of an indexed array on query. But you need to inspect the actual values, and note, you have no error checking anywhere. You also already have a username in `$u`, so if it's matched, you don't really need to get it from the row.

Comment: @Jared Farish I just tried some test code and the password does validate... so there is something else wrong. I essentially used the code from your answer so I am going to mark it as correct. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @PHaeLiX - Jared's code works well, but additionally have a look at this [example](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#bcrypt) that shows how to generate a safe salt from the random source of the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly more in-depth demonstration as what's found on the PHP `crypt()` man page:

```
// Only for demonstration, see mcrypt_create_iv() for a better salt:
//   http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php
$salt = substr(sha1(date('r')), rand(0, 17), 22);
$cost = 10;
$hash = '$2y$' . $cost . '$' . $salt;
$pass = 'mypass';
$notpass = 'notmypass';

$hashed = crypt($pass, "$hash");

echo "
Hash:
$hash

Hashed:
$hashed

Verified: 
" . crypt($pass, $hashed) . "

Not Verified: 
" . crypt($notpass, $hashed);
```

https://ignite.io/code/51323c3aec221e7b73000000

Which gives (at least this time):

```
Hash:
$2y$10$a80ded6289240c2e41a5e4

Hashed:
$2y$10$a80ded6289240c2e41a5euUFPvmt.sb6lBwOE.JTAdxQsDWmmM.Me

Verified: 
$2y$10$a80ded6289240c2e41a5euUFPvmt.sb6lBwOE.JTAdxQsDWmmM.Me

Not Verified: 
$2y$10$a80ded6289240c2e41a5euj06Emi8HigWM6BpqVFZ.ZtpA9wK5c8G
```

Comment: The generation of the salt could be improved, it should be generated from the random source of the OS. Concatenating MD5 and SHA1 will not improve the result in any way.

Comment: @martinstoeckli - If you look, it's not concatenating, and was only for the purposes of demonstration as it is. You could make the same point as the cost being fixed at `10` (probably low in many cases).

Comment: I only meant, that the salt would be better, if you leave out the MD5 and use SHA1 solely, the hint about `mcrypt_create_iv()` solves the problem though.

Comment: @martinstoeckli - I agree, hence the edit. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

To verify the password you need the salt that was used to create the first password hash. This salt is included in the output string of the `crypt()` function, and crypt can extract this salt from the password hash.

You can see well how it works when you look at the new hash functions from PHP 5.5 `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`...

```
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

...the function that verifies the login password, needs the hash of the first password. It then can extract the salt and the cost factor from this string, to hash the login password with the same parameters.

I can recommend this new functions, there is a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) for earlier versions.

Comment: how secure is this compared to something like blowfish though? I'm assuming these functions are better than the old md5?

Comment: @PHaeLiX - This function is actually just a wrapper around the crypt function, and generates a BCrypt hash (blowfish). It is written very well, especially the generation of the salt is done in a cryptographically safe way. So you could say, it's the best you can do nowadays.